# CIFS mount share with IPv6 link-local address on Ubuntu

Tags: ipv6, cifs, systemd-mount

I'm trying to mount a Windows share on a headless Linux computer with the following systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
  Description=mount network drive from harvester OBC
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service
  StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Mount]
  What=//192.168.X.Y/Users/User/Desktop/exchange
  Where=/home/me/exchange
  Options=username=me,password=secret,workgroup=WORKGROUP,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000
  Type=cifs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the IPv4 and host URL of the Windows computer change when I connect the two machines with a different network. However, the Windows computer's IPv6 stays the same: `fe80::1234:567:89ab%17` on `wlp1s0` (address partially obfuscated). So I'm wondering if it is possible to mount the exchange folder via an IPv6 address. I can successfully ping the IPv6.

So far I've tried:

```
What=//fe80::1234:567:89ab/Users/User/Desktop/exchange
```

```
What=//fe80::1234:567:89ab%17/Users/User/Desktop/exchange
```

```
What=//fe80::1234:567:89ab%wlp1s0/Users/User/Desktop/exchange
```

```
What=//fe80::1234:567:89ab%wlp1s0/17/Users/User/Desktop/exchange
```

For all of these I get an error telling me that the share was not found.

How can I make this work and connect to the Windows computer regardless of which WiFi is used to connect the two?

Comment: IPv6 addresses generally have to be contained within `[]`, so try `What=//[fe80::1234:567:89ab]/Users/User/Desktop/exchange` etc. Those semicolons tend to be recognised as a separator for the port & that confuses things.

Comment: Syntax aside, where does the `17` come from? Is it the interface index on the Linux machine or the WIndows machine?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I don't remember for sure. I think 17 was the scope id displayed with ipconfig on the Windows machine.

Comment: @Bib that didn't work.

Comment: @Joooeey: Yeah, that will not be useful here because it was displayed _on the Windows machine_ and has no meaning on any other machine. So you can safely rule out all variants that include `17` – the scope/zone index needs to be meaningful within the Linux system that's doing the connection.

Comment: okay, do I need to consider options with the scope ID from linux? And how to spell that scope_id? ifconfig outputs the scope_id in hex. Does systemd-mount/cifs take the scope_id as decimal or hex number? Or is it not necessary anyways?